# AWS Lambda using Python does not recognize the Redis library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis

Using Python 3.12 and AWS Lambda, I'm trying to run Redis, but it gives an error for an unrecognized library.

It's hard to believe that Redis is not a native Lambda library. Do I need to upload the Redis library manually, or is it under another name?

```
import json
import redis

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

**Error message:**

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'redis'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. AWS Lambda Runtime goes with a minimal set of pre-installed libraries.

However, you can include any libraries you're using.

```bash
> cd path/to/project/root               # Navigate to your project root
> mkdir package                         # Create a directory for dependencies
> pip install --target ./package redis  # Install dependencies into separated direcotry
> zip -r ../lambda_src.zip .            # Create an archive with source code and upload it to AWS
```

Please take into account that depending on your set up these steps may differ. For example if you're using `serverless` to manage Lambda functions you may use built-in support for packaging python projects with preferred dependency manager, e.g pipenv, poetry.

Links:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you can create redis layer and attach with your lambda function to resolve the issue.

```
mkdir packages
cd packages
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
 
mkdir python
cd python
pip install redis -t .
 
rm -rf *dist-info
cd..
zip -r requirements-package.zip python
```

Next, return to Lambda and navigate to Layers. Create a new layer and name it 'redis-layer.' Upload the ZIP file.

Once you have created the layer, add it to your Lambda function.

Or else you can directly install dependencies into your project folder and you can upload a zip

open your project directory and create requirements.txt file and add all dependencies that you required for your function.

run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t .
zip -r myfunction.zip .
```

Upload a zip to your lambda function.